# I want to read SMS from SD card

Tags: sd-card, sms

I have my SMS in my Nokia phone saved to the SD memory card in a folder called Private\1000484b\Mail2 (at least I think they are).

The folder contains files with no extension whatsoever (just files). I want to be able to read these SMS from my PC; and browse and manage them quickly.

The problem is I don't have my USB cable anymore, and my computer doesn't have blue tooth. Given the fact that Nokia suite could help in the previous cases. So only the card could be connected by a reader.

Is there a way that I could read my SMS when I need to, from the PC?

Comment: Did you try opening the file in Notepad(++)? Perhaps the SMS'es aren't even encoded and just plain test.

Comment: @mtak I did open some in Notepad (not sure what ++ means). Some messages have text that makes sense, and that text appears within some symbols. Other messages are just a bunch of meaningless symbols.

Comment: Could you post a couple of the readable and unreadable messages? People might get an idea for a solution without having to buy a Nokia phone :)

Comment: @mtak This is part of what the symbols look like (I couldn't copy whole messages without including private info like cell numbers ;)) h< h<     Kژچ p E   : c      :     f      %:

Comment: @mtak I would also like to add that some symbols within those I wrote above couldn't get copied here, i.e. symbols that look like crosses, etc..

Comment: @mtak Any clue? I have checked most of the messages and all of them seem to reveal the sender's/recipient's cell numbers. I can't also copy them here, the browser doesn't seem to understand some of these symbols as I pointed out earlier. The symbols above are from a message. They come before the actual message (from one I could read), and similar symbols come after the message itself then the cell numbers; all in the same line.

Comment: I'm sure you can order another USB cable online. There's always resellers of legacy tech out there. It could even be on Amazon or Ebay. You could alternatively get a USB Bluetooth dongle for pretty cheap online as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have USB or Bluetooth, then IRDA is another option.

> Please note that only those modem drivers that are using either cable 
>   or Bluetooth or are present currently will show the 
>   port they are using. 
>   Modems that are using IrDA or PC Card slot as connection method will 
>   only be listed but not showing the actual port they will use.

- [How To Connect to Peripheral Devices with IrDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313296)
- [Installing Nokia IrDA Modem INF Manually](http://nds1.nokia.com/phones/files/guides/Nokia_6100_WinXP_Manual_modem_inf_installation.pdf)(pdf)